# Ngrams without words orders in Hive

Tags: hive, explode, lateral

Creation of name_tab:

```
CREATE TABLE name_tab (country string,
new_item ARRAY<STRUCT<ngram:array<string>,
estfrequency:double>>);
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE name_tab
SELECT country, ngrams(sentences(var2),3,100) as word_map
FROM bdd 
GROUP BY country;
```

Creation of name_tab_new :

```
CREATE TABLE name_tab_new (country string, ngram1 string, ngram2 string,  ngram3 string, estfrequency double);
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE name_tab_new
SELECT country , X.ngram[0], X.ngram[1], X.ngram[2], X.estfrequency
FROM name_tab
LATERAL VIEW explode(new_item) Z as X;
```

These requests in Hive work. It creates ngrams by country. 
The problem: for one country there is a difference between this ngram `{aa, bb, cc}` and this ngram `{bb, aa, cc}`.

I want a solution which the words orders don't matters. For one country, i want no différence between `{aa, bb, cc}` and `{bb, aa, cc}`. I want just one of them.

Thank you very much

**Results example:**

*England, bread, sandwich, juice, 120

England, desk, chair, tool, 54

England, sandwich, bread, juice, 32

Italy, sea, Roma, Coliseo, 47*

**Actually, I want that:**

*England, bread, sandwich, juice, 152

England, desk, chair, tool, 54

Italy, sea, Roma, Coliseo, 47*

I hope There is an option in the ngrams function for not taking account the order.

In the table bdd, the variable "var2" is a list of several words separated by a blanck.

In the table name_tab, we have:

**First line** 
England, {"ngram":["bread","sandwich","juice"],"estfrequency":120.0},  {"ngram":["desk","chair","tool"],"estfrequency":54.0},  {"ngram":["sandwich","bread","juice"],"estfrequency":32.0}

**Second line** 
Italy,  {"ngram":["sea","Roma","Coliseo"],"estfrequency":47.0}

Comment: Your question is not clear, supply a data sample including the required results.

Comment: I had an example. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this example relates this post

Comment: In the table bdd, the variable "var2" is a list of several words separated by a blanck.

Comment: So add the data sample

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**

```
with t as (select 'a  b a c c a b b a a a a c c b c a b c a b' as mycol)

select      sort_array(e.ngram) as ngram
           ,sum(e.estfrequency) as estfrequency

from       (select  explode(ngrams(sentences(mycol),2,1000)) e

            from    t
            ) t

group by    sort_array(e.ngram)
;
```

---

```
+-----------+--------------+
|   ngram   | estfrequency |
+-----------+--------------+
| ["a","a"] | 3.0          |
| ["a","b"] | 6.0          |
| ["a","c"] | 5.0          |
| ["b","b"] | 1.0          |
| ["b","c"] | 3.0          |
| ["c","c"] | 2.0          |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Dudu. Where i put the variable country. It doesn't work when i put it in the group by

Comment: `mycol` is the equivalent to `var2`

Comment: Of course. But i want to group by the variable "country"

Comment: Have you seen my comment to your post?

Comment: You talk about your comment "mycol is the équivalent to var2"

Comment: No, my comment "So add the data sample"

Comment: It's like your example but with a supplementary column named country. I want for each country the number of ngrams sorted

Comment: Add the data sample

Comment: Hello Dudu. I add a new subject more complete with an example : "ngrams combination of words hive"